# Minecraft Forge Modding: Starting Minecraft from Eclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So, I have been coding for mine craft on some occasions. My friend asked be to create him a mod. I am starting to understand Forge API. I have previously coded of Bukkit/Spigot etc.. and I have come across this error when trying to load Minecraft from eclipse using `Run -> Runconfigurations -> <mymodname>_Client`. This is what happens: (btw I the main class in this configuration is `GradleStart` and the project is MDKExample, have not changed the name yet):

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by GradleStart (file:/C:/Users/Lucas/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2808/start/) to field java.lang.ClassLoader.sys_paths

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of GradleStart

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operationsWARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

[18:12:51] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Extra: []

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleForgeHacks.searchCoremods(GradleForgeHacks.java:85)

at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:86)

at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25)
```

I looked in to the bigger error and the problem is a `ClassCastException` and is at `GradleStart` class at line 25 which is `(new GradleStart()).launch(args);` in the main method. It also goes on at `GradleStartCommon` class at line 86, which is `net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleForgeHacks.searchCoremods(this);` which is in a protected method called `launch` which params of args ( a String[]). Also the error occurs at `GradleForgeHacks` at line 85 which is `URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) GradleStartCommon.class.getClassLoader();`, so it looks like this line is the main problem. It says `URLClassLoader` can't be cast, is there a way I could remove the `(URLClassLoader` part from my mod folder?

I am using java 8 bc I could not start gradlew setupDecompWorkspace and gradlew eclipse with any other java version eg. 1.11 (i think).

FYI: I am using Windows 10 April 2018, on bootcamp MACOSX (windows on mac its like any windows device)

Comment: How did you set up Forge?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XN91U323 I answered there (too long)

Comment: My comment appears to have been lost. `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace and gradlew eclipse` was the bit I was looking for, and if you did that, then I don't know what's wrong. My only suggestion is to start (the Forge install process) over.